# Using Memoization in recursion solution causing wrong answer

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying to solve Minimum cost of tickets question on leetecode. You can see the description here https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-cost-for-tickets/

I have following recursive solution which passes the initial test cases sucessfully
But the memoization is giving wrong solution for Input:
**days= [1,4,6,7,8,20]
cost= [2,7,15]**

**Expected= 11
Actual= 12**

Please help me figuring out what is wrong with my memoization.

I have used 1D dp because cost is just accumulating so we just need 1D dp to store result for the respective days. I tried debugging and dry run but could not figure out what the problem is.

**RECURSION SOLUTION(CORRECT OUTPUT):-**

`

```
class Solution {
  public int mincostTickets(int[] days, int[] costs) {
    return solveTicketsCostRec(days, costs, 0, 0);
  }

  private int solveTicketsCostRec(int[] days, int[] costs, int cost, int daysCovered) {
    if (daysCovered >= days.length) {
      return cost;
    }

    int cost1 = solveTicketsCostRec(days, costs, cost + costs[0], daysCovered + 1);

    //7 day pass
    int days1 = days[daysCovered] + 7;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < days.length && days1 > days[i]) {
      i++;
    }
    int cost2 = solveTicketsCostRec(days, costs, cost + costs[1], i);


    //30 day pass
    int days2 = days[daysCovered] + 30;
    i = 0;
    while (i < days.length && days2 > days[i]) {
      i++;
    }
    int cost3 = solveTicketsCostRec(days, costs, cost + costs[2], i);
    
    return Math.min(cost1, Math.min(cost2, cost3));
  }
}
```

`

**MEMOIZATION SOLUTION(GIVING WRONG OUTPUT):-**
`

```
//Memoization
class Solution {
  public int mincostTickets(int[] days, int[] costs) {
    int dp[] = new int[days.length];
    Arrays.fill(dp, -1);
    return solveTicketsCostMem2(days, costs, 0, 0, dp);
  }

  private int solveTicketsCostMem2(int[] days, int[] costs, int cost, int daysCovered, int[] dp) {
    if (daysCovered >= days.length) {
      return cost;
    }

    if (dp[daysCovered] != -1) {
      return dp[daysCovered];
    }
    int cost1 = solveTicketsCostMem2(days, costs, cost + costs[0],
            daysCovered + 1, dp);

    //7 day pass
    int days1 = days[daysCovered] + 7;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < days.length && days1 > days[i]) {
      i++;
    }
    int cost2 = solveTicketsCostMem2(days, costs, cost + costs[1],
            i, dp);


    //30 day pass
    int days2 = days[daysCovered] + 30;
    i = 0;
    while (i < days.length && days2 > days[i]) {
      i++;
    }
    int cost3 = solveTicketsCostMem2(days, costs, cost + costs[2],
            i, dp);
    
    dp[daysCovered]=Math.min(cost1, Math.min(cost2, cost3));
    return dp[daysCovered];
  }

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try initializing the array with **Integer.MAX_Value** and not by -1 and calculate your cost2 and cost3 by using days you already covered **daysCovered** in while loops, instead of i=0;

Here **Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE);**

```
class Solution {
  public int mincostTickets(int[] days, int[] costs) {
    int dp[] = new int[days.length];
    Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return solveTicketsCostMem2(days, costs, 0, 0, dp);
  }
```

Here **if (dp[daysCovered] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)**

```
if (dp[daysCovered] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      return dp[daysCovered];
    }
```

//7 day pass - **int i = daysCovered;**

```
  int i = daysCovered;
    while (i < days.length && days1 > days[i]) {
      i++;
    }
```

//30 day pass **int i = daysCovered;**

```
i = daysCovered;
while (i < days.length && days2 > days[i]) {
  i++;
}
```

---

Tried this solution with bottoms up

```
class Solution {
  public int mincostTickets(int[] days, int[] costs) {
    int maxDay = days[days.length - 1];
    int dp[] = new int[maxDay + 1];
    Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    dp[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= maxDay; i++) {
      if (!isTravelDay(days, i)) {
        dp[i] = dp[i - 1];
        continue;
      }
      dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], dp[i - 1] + costs[0]);
      dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], dp[Math.max(0, i - 7)] + costs[1]);
      dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], dp[Math.max(0, i - 30)] + costs[2]);
    }

    return dp[maxDay];
  }

  private boolean isTravelDay(int[] days, int day) {
    for (int d: days) {
      if (d == day) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it same result : -(

Comment: Trying to find what's wrong with the Memoization(top-down), as it is a recursive solution added a solution with less complexity O(maxDay)